# Is there a safe, ethical, way to get rid of old gas?

Tags: lawn-mower, disposal, gasoline

Normally I'm pretty good about buying just enough at the beginning of the spring.  Last year my grass continued to grow into December so I ended up with nearly a gallon of extra gas.  I don't feel like clogging my 1 year old lawn mower carburetor, but I'm not sure what do do with it.

If the suggestion is the same as any of these, It's probably not something I would put under the category of safe or ethical.

http://www.survivalistboards.com/showthread.php?t=190269

Comment: I have a gas can labeled "fire starter", where I put old gas.  And as you may have guessed, I use it to start fires (controlled bonfires).  Not sure how environmentally friendly it is, but it can't be any worse than a flare stack. Though I guess that only works, if you have enough land to have bonfires.

Comment: My lawn and garden store takes old gas off your hands.  I asked one time what they do with it, they said a farmer takes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not wish to risk using it, even though it is probably only 6 months old, I would take it to where ever your community recycles hazardous wastes.  In my community, the recycle center has the following information on it's website:

> Fuels and fuel oils are petroleum products that are used in many types of engines, lamps, heaters, furnaces, stoves, and as solvents. Fuel oils come from crude petroleum and are refined to meet specifications for each use. Fuel oils are mixtures of aliphatic (open chain and cyclic compounds that are similar to open chain compounds) and aromatic (benzene and compounds similar to benzene) petroleum hydrocarbons. In addition, they may contain small amounts of nitrogen, sulfur, and other elements as additives. Fuel oils are distinguished from each other primarily by their boiling point ranges, chemical additives, and uses. Fuel oils include: Kerosene, coal oil, diesel fuel, home heating oil, and Gasoline. All fuels and fuel oils should be disposed of as a hazardous waste.

In this community there is no cost for this service.

Comment: Well I bought the fuel over a year ago. Usually getting rid of fuel oils isn't hard because furnaces can often burn them. As for this excerpt, gasoline is indeed aliphatic but consists of shorter, fast burning "explosive ", HC's like octane and hexane. I've never heard of gasoline being referred to as a fuel oil. But I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

You can slowly mix bits of it into your car. Not the whole gallon, mind you, but in small doses it shouldn't hurt your car. Or, if you don't like that, slowly mix some of it into your lawnmower with fresh gas. As long as it's not go 2-cycle oil it should be fine

Comment: Unfortunately it is